# Manejo array y matriz - PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Buenos días comunidad,

Soy nuevo en Python, me está costando tirar para alante.

Tengo un archivo csv con tres columnas, necesito contar las repeticiones de los elementos de la primera columna.

Importo el csv y lo transformo a un array de listas con cada fila del csv:

```
#leer el fichero csv
reader = csv.reader(open("archivo.csv","r"),delimiter=",")
for row in reader: # each row is a list
        resultados.append(row)
```

Convierto el array a una matriz con numpy (numpy.asmatrix)

De la primera columna, necesito sacar las repeticiones de los elementos, es decir, si la matriz tiene la siguiente forma:

```
[ X1 Y1 Z1
  X2 Y2 Z2
  x1 Y3 Z3 ]
```

Necesito obtener X1 = 2 y X2 = 1.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si alguna respuesta és satisfatória a su problema, no olvides de aceptarla: [mire](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/120826)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo compreendi, y **queres contar elementos**, hay diversas formas de hacerlo, abajo algunas:

Con `numpy.array`, puedes hacer un `dict` (`elemento` como llave, y la `cantidad`, como valor):

```
dict(zip(*numpy.unique(np_array, return_counts=True)))
```

Obtener el mismo con `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
collections.Counter(np_array)
```

Si necesitas sólo de un específico, puedes usar `numpy.count_nonzero`:

```
numpy.count_nonzero(np_array == 3)
```

Con `list`:

```
list(np_array).count(3)
```